# How does it works Observable.take() after a mergeDelayError()?

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I have some code like this:

```
    Set<Something> set = HashSet<>();
    // [...]
    return Observable.mergeDelayError(
            Observable.from(set)
                    .map(something -> process(something)))
            .take(1);
```

According to the documentation:

> mergeDelayError: Flattens an Observable that emits Observables into
>   one Observable, in a way that allows an Observer to receive all
>   successfully emitted items from all of the source Observables without
>   being interrupted by an error notification from one of them.

So far, I understand. **My question is about the method take()**: Will it wait for all Observables return something before take the first result, or it will take the first result from the first finished Observable?

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it wait for all Observables return something before take the first result

That's right

**UPD**

According to that test it returns first emitted item

```
    Observable.mergeDelayError(
            Observable.just(null)
                    .doOnNext(x -> {
                        throw new RuntimeException();
                    }),
            Observable.just(1).delay(70, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
            Observable.just(2).delay(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .take(1)
            .subscribe(System.out::print);
```

Comment: In that case, the method take() will take the 1st result from the Observable that finish first, right? Or is it unpredictable?